# What does "coproduct of $\Bbb{Z}*\Bbb{Z}$ of $\Bbb{Z}$ by itself" mean?

Tags: category-theory

> Prove that the group $F(\{x,y\})$ is a coproduct of $\Bbb{Z}*\Bbb{Z}$ of $\Bbb{Z}$ by itself in the category **Grp**.

What does "coproduct of $\Bbb{Z}*\Bbb{Z}$ of $\Bbb{Z}$ by itself" mean?

Comment: Which part of it are you unsure of? Do you know about coproducts?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft- Yes I know about coproducts. I was wondering what the rest of the phrase means.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft- For example, I know what "coproduct of $A$ and $B$" means.

Comment: The coproduct of $X$ by itself simply means the coproduct of $X$ with $X$. The author is just explaining what they mean by $\Bbb Z*\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Perhaps there's a language issue: in American English I'd say "coproduct _with_ itself", not "by".

Comment: This is an exercise in Aluffi. The proper quotation is ""Prove that the group $F(\{x,y\})$ is a coproduct $\Bbb Z*\Bbb Z$ of $\Bbb Z$ by itself in the category $\mathbf{Grp}$." In other words, he is saying "Prove that $F(\{x,y\})\simeq \Bbb Z*\Bbb Z$."

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/663120/free-product-of-groups-as-coproduct.

Comment: You have an extra "of" in your quotation OP.

Answer (score 2):

You know what $A * B$ is for groups $A,B$? Now put $A=B=\mathbb{Z}$. Then you know what $\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}$ is.

If $S,T$ are sets, then $F(S \sqcup T) = F(S) * F(T)$. This is formal (left adjoints preserve colimits). If $S = \{x\}$, then $F(S) = \mathbb{Z}$. It follows that $F(\{x,y\})=\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: $A*B$ is the free group generated by the elements of $A\cup B$. Hence, $\Bbb{Z}*\Bbb{Z}$ would be the free group generated by the elements of $\Bbb{Z}\cup \Bbb{Z}$. Shouldn't this free group be equal to $\Bbb{Z}$?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg : "If $S=\{s\}$, then $F(x)=\mathbb Z$" is not very explanatory... I imagine you wanted to write "If $S = \{ s \}$, then $F(S) = \mathbb Z$".

Comment: @AyushKhaitan : No, $A \ast B$ is certainly not the free group generated by the elements of $A\cup B$ : for example, $\mathbb Z/2 \ast 1$ is $\mathbb Z/2$ which isn't free at all. What you probably mean is that if $A =F(S)$ and $B=F(T)$ then $A\ast B = F(S\cup T)$ : but this is false, Martin gives the right property in his answer, i.e. $A \ast B = F(S \sqcup T)$, and the categorical justification of it.

Answer (score 1):

A way to prove that some object is a coproduct is to show that it satisfies the universal property.

The homomorphisms $\varphi$ from $\Bbb Z\ \left(\cong F(\{x\})\right)$ to any group $G$ are determined by the element $\varphi(1)\ \in G$, which can be arbitrary.

The homomorphisms $\varphi$ from $F(\{x,y\})$ to $G$ are determined by the elements  $\varphi(x)$ and $\varphi(y)\ \in G$, which can be arbitrary, independently to each other.

Hence, whenever we have a pair of group morphisms $\alpha,\beta:\Bbb Z\to G$, there will be a unique map $F(\{x,y\}\to G$ [the one which picks $\alpha(1)$ for $x$ and $\beta(1)$ for $y$] that makes the coproduct diagram commutative.